Android apollo3 schema not found
I'm trying to use local schema from this url:
https://spacex-production.up.railway.app/
In my data module I have
apollo {
    service("RocketsGraphQL") {
        packageName.set("com.example.data")
        schemaFiles.from("src/main/graphql/schema.graphqls")
    }
}


Error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No schema file found in:
In my schema.graphqls
""""""
type Address {
    """"""
    address: String

    """"""
    city: String

    """"""
    state: String
}


As per Apollo3, you should explicitly set srcDir().
Reference: Specifying schema and .graphql files
This should be sufficient. I don't even have schemaFiles.from in my app:
apollo {
    service("RocketsGraphQL") {
        srcDir("src/main/graphql")
        packageName.set("com.example.data")
    }
}

